# How to repeat radio button in a table using foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I have a table, in that table there have two radio button, and the table data populate from database, I am using foreach loop, the radio button is repeated in a row but when i select one radio button another is deselect automatically,

Here is my code through which i want achive my task.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'input[type=radio][name=test]', function() 
            { 
            var clicked = localStorage['clicked'];
           $('.' + related_class).prop('disabled', false); 

           $('input[type=radio][name=test]').not(':checked').each(function()
             { var other_class = $(this).val(); 
          $('.' + other_class).prop('disabled', true); 
        }); 
    });
 });   

 <table>    
<c:forEach items="${List2}" var="as">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="Id" value="${as.id}"/>${as.id}</td>  
                <td><input type="hidden" name="RuleName" value="${as.ruleName}"/>${as.ruleName}</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="fixed" value="Fixed"></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" name="repeats" VALUE="radio20"><select name="Repeats" style="width: 80px;" >
                        <c:forEach items="${listfrequency}" var="freq">  
                             <option value="${freq.frequencyName}"/>
                             <c:out value="${freq.frequencyName}" />
                            </c:forEach></select></td>

                <td>

            </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Use unique name for the set of radio you want to make a group;

Comment: try to verify that your radio button have not the same name

Comment: Are you saying you actually want multiple selection? Use check boxes not radio buttons.

Comment: @ itzmukeshy how do i use unique name..??

Answer (score 0):

It is because the name of the all radio inputs are same (`repeats` and `fixed`).

You need to make them unique for each row so that by selecting one radio button other doesn't deselect automatically. Best way to make them unique is append index value of foreach loop to the name of radio buttons.

I don't know the syntax how to get index/counter value of foreach loop in your example. But it would be as follow.

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="fixed${indexValue}" value="Fixed"></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" name="repeats${indexValue}" VALUE="radio20"><select name="Repeats" style="width: 80px;" >
                        <c:forEach items="${listfrequency}" var="freq">  
                             <option value="${freq.frequencyName}"/>
                             <c:out value="${freq.frequencyName}" />
                            </c:forEach></select></td>
```

> ${indexValue} replace this with your actual index/counter variable.